# Ring sentence is true in field of characteristic 0

Tags: logic

**The problem:**

> Let $L$ be the language of rings and $\phi$ an $L$-sentence. Suppose that
>   for every natural number $n$ there is a prime $p > n$ and a field $F$
>   of char $p$, such that $\phi$ holds in $F$. Show there is a field $K$
>   of char $0$ such that $\phi$ holds in $K$.

**My attempt**

Call the language $L' = L \cup \{c \}$ for a random constant. 
Let $$T = \phi \cup \{\neg \underbrace{(c \cdot c \cdot \dots = e)}_\text{ $n$ times}, n \in \mathcal{N}\}.$$ Then we need to show that $T$ is consistent. By the compactness theorem, we can show that every finite subtheory is consistent. Every finite subtheory $T'$ is of the form $\phi \cup \{\underbrace{(c \cdot c \cdot \dots = e)}_\text{ $n$ times}, n < N\}$ with $N \in \mathcal{N}$. By assumption there is a field of char $p>N$ that makes the theory $T'$ true. $\blacksquare$

Is this a correct proof? I'm not sure if I need to add the constant at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's basically right. A couple comments:

- You seem to have mixed up multiplication and addition: "$\cdot$" should everywhere be replaced with "$+$."
- You should write "$\{\phi\}\cup...$" rather than "$\phi\cup...$" - of course it's clear what you mean, but it is wrong as written.
- You do not in fact need to add the constant (although it's a reasonable instinct). Simply let $\chi_n$ be the sentence "$\exists x(x+...+x\not=e)$" ($n$ many $x$s), and consider the theory $T\cup \{\chi_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.